# Ubuntu Graphics Experience is fallback

Tags: drivers, graphics, virtualbox

The graphics experience is in fallback mode for me. And I checked the settings and it says the *graphics driver is Chromium*. I am running Ubuntu 11.10 in a virtual box. I didn't like unity much. So reverted from it long back. and it was working fine till now.

How do I fix the issue. No desktop effects is working now!

**Note:**
Host OS Windows 7
Graphics ATI Radeon HD series
Virtual box version 4.1.6
**Another Guest OS Ubuntu Is working fine..**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the virtual box guest-additions for the virtual machine? After a downgrade it might be necessary to re-install them if you haven't used dkms during the first install which automatically rebuilds the virtualbox kernel module in case the kernel version changes due to down/up-grade

Comment: Yes i did re install the guest additions.. i reset gnome settings.. i also reset the compiz settings.. no use.. i could just enable the transparency of the terminal in the gconf-editor

Comment: Have you changed something on your main desktop which runs virtual box that could be affecting the use of vb additions within ? Also, why not try 12.10 beta inside VB since it has Unity running 3d effects all the time, even without proper 3d drivers it reverts to software usage...

Comment: no.. my other virtual box guest ubuntu is running just fine...

Comment: Please add the following to your question: host OS, graphics card, virtualbox version and source. Also, what did you do before it stopped working?

Comment: and i don't like unity much.. its not very productive for me.. i like the old fashioned way..

Comment: @Takkat details added

Comment: @jaykay90: any reason you didn't upgrade Virtual Box? Yours is eight releases back (at present 4.2.0)?

Comment: @Takkat if that's a reason the other guest ubuntu which was a clone that i took several months back shouldn't also work properly right.. I guess i mush have messed up with some settings...

Answer (score 0):

Check that your virtual machine still has the option "Enable 3D Acceleration" checked (in VMs settings -> Display).

Comment: Yeah.. it's enabled already...